# Is there are way to fix when allowing the use of GPS, the code execution button must be pressed again on Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm trying to make a button that takes the coordinates from the current location, calls the city from API and returns the name of the city in the searchbar.

At the moment when the button is pressed, it first asks for GPS permission but once you enable it it stops executing the logic down.

After permission, you need to press the same button again to change the name of the city in the search engine. Is there a way when the user allows the use of his location to execute the code without having to press a second time.

Code:

```
        async void OnGetGPSLocation(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
     
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && status == PermissionStatus.Disabled)
        {
            _ = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
           
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

                if (location != null)
                {
                    WeatherForecast16DaysCoordinates weatherBindingData = await _restServiceForecastCoords.GetCity(GenerateRequestUriForecast3(ConstantsForecast16DaysCoords.WeatherbitEndPoint3, location));
                    var cityCoord = weatherBindingData.CityName;
                    _cityEntry.Text = cityCoord;
                }
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert" + Environment.NewLine + "Something is wrong.", "You have some errors: " + Environment.NewLine + fnsEx.ToString(), "OK");
            }
            catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert" + Environment.NewLine + "Something is wrong.", "You have some errors: " + Environment.NewLine + fneEx.ToString(), "OK");
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert" + Environment.NewLine + "Something is wrong.", "You have some errors: " + Environment.NewLine + pEx.ToString(), "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert" + Environment.NewLine + "Something is wrong.", "You have some errors: " + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }
        }
    }
```

My second problem with GPS is when GPS is disconnected from the user's device. How to forward it directly to the settings to activate it.

Comment: do you want to continuously monitor the user location?

Comment: Yes if possible..

Comment: use the GeoLocator plugin - https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/LocationChanges.html

Comment: And how to do in one click after the message to allow the GPS to execute my code that I put  ?

Comment: I just linked to docs and samples that show you how to do this.  Please take the time to read them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when GPS is disconnected from the user's device. How to forward it directly to the settings to activate it.

If you want to allow the permission again when user deny it you could check the following code.

```
var bundleId = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier;
var url = new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString + "&path=LOCATION/" + bundleId);

if(UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(url))
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: I write for iOS platform not android

Comment: Yes, it is for iOS . Did you have a try ?